# Trying understand what underscore means

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the sample code from a VBA function in an excel file. I am expecting the variables to be cell numbers, but have no inkling what the underscore means here.

Can somebody explain to me what the "_" (underscore) means in this function

```
Set WS1 = Worksheets("input")
'
QTX = 1
  
DB1 = WS1.Range("DB1_")
 
If WS1.Range("WB1_") = " " Then
    ZZ = 0
    WB = 0
Else
    ZZ = 1
    WB1 = WS1.Range("WB1_")
End If
 
TW1 = WS1.Range("TW1_")
TW = WS1.Range("TW_")
ROWX = WS1.Range("ROWX_")
HNO = WS1.Range("HNO_")
EL = WS1.Range("EL_")
n = WS1.Range("N_")
QA = WS1.Range("QA_")
CUT = 0.27
'
```

Comment: Nothing more than being the last character in those names of ranges.

Comment: This "DB1_" is not a normal cell address this is a named range. You can give a range or a cell a name (see [Create a named range from selected cells in a worksheet](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-named-range-from-selected-cells-in-a-worksheet-fd8905ed-1130-4cca-9bb0-ad02b7e594fd)). And that is what happened here: Someone gave a cell the name `DB1_`. The underscore is used because `DB1` cannot be used to name a cell because it is already referencing to column `DB` row `1`. But with `DB1_` you can name any other cell like `A1` as `DB1_`.

Comment: Just as an aside, I am pretty sure that the original author deliberately named ranges always ending with an underscore expressly so that they couldn't be mistaken for a cell reference.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock Yes maybe, but the main issue would probably be `DB1` is already referencing to column `DB` row `1` which makes `DB1` impossible to use as name for a range, and therefore `DB1_` had to be used. Similar issue with the others.

Answer (score 0):

> I am expecting the variables to be cell numbers,

Using a named range has it's advantages.

Select a cell and name the cell in the name box.

You can reference the named cell.
Normally using a formula on the sheet, you can drag the cell around and the formula will change accordingly.

Using the named range in code will ensure you are referring to the named range and not a hard coded cell address.

[image]

The code is referencing the named cell, drag the cell around and run the code.

```
Sub Msg_MyNamedRange()
    T1 = Range("MyNamedRange")
    MsgBox T1
End Sub
```

If you wanted to name a cell T1, you can't because T1 already exists on the sheet, you can add the underscore.
Name the cell T1_